# Row locks on selects

Tags: sql-server, select, locking, concurrency

```
select t.*, row_number() over (
    partition by t.Entity_Identifier 
    order by t.Message_Sequence
    ) as seqnum 
from Process_Activity t (ROWLOCK) 
where t.Process_Id =
```

Is it possible for this select to retrieve a different number of rows based on whether it can lock a row or not?

We have a situation where the select will bring back 18 rows when there is another process performing an insert/update on the same table, but the select will bring back 33 rows (the correct amount) when the other process is not running.

I feel the `ROWLOCK` is getting in the way. Why use a rowlock on a select?

Comment: What is the database isolation level ? Is it set to snapshot ?

Comment: If rows are being skipped,that might suggest that the READPAST hint is also being used.